# How to write a small tokenizer in Python?

Tags: python, parsing, interpreter

Normally, Python calls functions by

```
func(arg0, arg1)
```

But I would like to change to

```
func arg0 arg1
```

For example,

```
#Something...
cmd = input()
interpret(cmd)
#Something...
```

If I input `'func arg0 arg1'`, then I expect Python to execute `func(arg0, arg1)`.

**Args will contain string, so that we can't simply split words.**

Actually, I would like to write some scripts to use on my mobile. So it would be a little annoying to type parentheses.

Comment: So you want to rewrite the Python parser to create your own language...? I think that's a bit out of scope here.

Comment: @deceze No. Because I would like to use it on a terminal on my phone. It's annoying to type parentheses on my phone.

Comment: So you just want to split the first word from the input, look up the function by that name, and call it with the rest of the arguments like `f(*args)`...?

Comment: Yes. But arg may be a string like `'Hello, World!'. So I think it should not simply split them. Should have a little parser I suppose.

Comment: @ZhipengYANG So it's just `()` that's bugging you - what about all the other symbols `'{}[]+-*/"#` etc... that you're almost always going to have to use?

Comment: F# sometimes allows you to omit parentheses in that situation. Have you considered trying F#?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 No. Because on Android's Termux, it doesn't support neither F# nor Haskell.

Comment: @deceze It's a little bit different to that question. I don't want to write an entirre language. I just want to simplify how I call functions on mobile.

Comment: In the end you *are* looking to create a new mini language. If you need to take strings with spaces etc. into account, you need a parser, and *boom*, you're in DSL territory.

Comment: @deceze As there are answers, how could I delete the question?

Answer (score 0):

if none of the args contains whitespace you could do

```
fn_args=cmd.split()
python_code="%s(%s)" % (fn[0], ", ".join(fn_args[1:]))
eval(python_code)
```

Edit:

If it is not that simple you should have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html and https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html but these require some preparation before you can execute arbitrary code

Edit2:

If you do not need your args to be exact python, you could parse them as json [with the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder.raw_decode)

you could do it like

```
import json
cmd='fname "a" "b" 1'
fn,sep,args=cmd.strip().partition(" ")
end=0
largs=[]
d=json.JSONDecoder()
while end < len(args):
    args=args[end:].strip()
    arg,end=d.raw_decode(args)
    largs.append(arg)
exec(fn)(*largs) # better look into exec docs
```

Comment: Actually there will be spaces and commas.

Comment: @ZhipengYANG Added links for not-that-simple cases

Comment: @ZhipengYANG Added JSON hack

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
class  tryClass:
    def callFunction(self, arg, arg2):
        print("In call")
        print(arg)
        print(arg2)

input = str(input())
input = input.split(" ")
funcName = input[0]
my_cls = tryClass()

method = getattr(my_cls, funcName)
method(input[1], input[2])
```

If I put in input callFunction hello world it works :)

Answer (score 0):

All I want is a simple tokenizer. And I would like to run functions by calling `eval()`. So that's what I did for my project.

Here's the result:

```
>>> tokenizer('func 123 abc')
[('func', 'func'), ('arg', '123'), ('arg', 'abc')]
>>> tokenizer('func 123.5 abc')
[('func', 'func'), ('arg', '123.5'), ('arg', 'abc')]
>>> tokenizer('func 123.5 abc "Hello, World!"')
[('func', 'func'), ('arg', '123.5'), ('arg', 'abc'), ('arg', 'Hello, World!')]
>>> tokenizer("func 123.5 abc 'Hello, World!'")
[('func', 'func'), ('arg', '123.5'), ('arg', 'abc'), ('arg', 'Hello, World!')]
```

**Attentsion: This may not suitable for everyone, this's not a complete parser or tokenizer.**

Code:

```
def isNumber(cmd):
    try:
        int(cmd)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        try:
            float(cmd)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False
    return False

def isWord(cmd):
    if len(cmd) == 0:
        return False
    if cmd[0].isalpha():
        for i in cmd[1:]:
            if not i.isalpha() and i != '_' and i != '-':
                return False
        return True
    return False
def spaceParser(cmd):
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(cmd)):
        if cmd[i] == ' ':
            continue
        break
    return cmd[i:]

def funcNameParser(cmd):
    cmd = spaceParser(cmd)
    i = 0
    word = ''
    for i in range(len(cmd)):
        if cmd[i] != ' ':
            word += cmd[i]
        else:
            break
    if i + 1 > len(word):
        return (word, cmd[i:])
    return (word, cmd[i+1:])

def argumentParser(cmd):
    cmd = spaceParser(cmd)
    if cmd[0] == '\'':
        word = ''
        i = 0
        for i in range(1, len(cmd)):
            if cmd[i] != '\'':
                word += cmd[i]
            else:
                return (word, cmd[i+1:])
        assert False, 'Fatal exception: String not finished.'
    if cmd[0] == '"':
        word = ''
        i = 0
        for i in range(1, len(cmd)):
            if cmd[i] != '"':
                word += cmd[i]
            else:
                return (word, cmd[i+1:])
        assert False, 'Fatal exception: String not finished.'            
    i = 0
    word = ''
    for i in range(len(cmd)):
        if cmd[i] != ' ':
            word += cmd[i]
        else:
            break
    assert isWord(word) or isNumber(word), 'Fatal exception: Not a valid name.'
    if i + 1 > len(word):
        return (word, cmd[i:]) 
    return (word, cmd[i+1:])

def tokenizer(cmd):
    token = []
    result = funcNameParser(cmd)
    token += [('func', result[0])]
    while len(result[1]) != 0:
        result = argumentParser(result[1])
        token += [('arg', result[0])]
    return token
```

Answer (score 0):

The builtin `shlex` module is probably what you want:

```
>>> import shlex
>>> cmd = "func arg0 arg1 'arg2 has spaces'"
>>> list(shlex.shlex(cmd))
['func', 'arg0', 'arg1', "'arg2 has spaces'"]
```

If you can trust the input, then actually calling this will look like:

```
>>> tokens = list(shlex.shlex(cmd))
>>> # here is a stupid func function that reverses its input args
>>> func = lambda *args: print(*reversed(args))
>>> eval(tokens[0])(*tokens[1:])
'arg2 has spaces' arg1 arg0
```